# Emacs 23 avail melpa package manager

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Im a newbie in emacs. I am using emacs 23 on a shared development server without root access. I want to use melpa which has more packages available. Is there any way I can use melpa on emacs 23(without upgrading)?

(I tried to built from source like I did for vi tmux etc, but emacs has lot of dependencies like build essentials. )

Thanks Prasanth

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ELPA was available as an external library prior to being included in Emacs 24 by default, and can be added to Emacs 23 like any other library.

It looks to me as if the old http://tromey.com/elpa/install.html would not be useful for MELPA, but https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc10 ("How packages work in Emacs 23") has a suggestion which sounds like it would do the trick?

However, the package ecosystem really took off starting from Emacs 24, which means a great many packages *depend* on Emacs 24 or above. You will undoubtedly have a more limited range of packages available to you in Emacs 23.